# LVM partition issue

Tags: lvm

I have a server with two disks (sda, sdb). Both disks have 280GB storage. The first disk uses 50GB for the OS. SDB has no partitions at all.

```
/dev/sda1  *         4096   1050623   1046528   511M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         1050624 103448575 102397952  48.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       103448576 104495103   1046528   511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       104495104 586072367 481577264 229.6G  5 Extended
```

I now want to create a new physical volume:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda4 /dev/sdb
  Device /dev/sda4 not found (or ignored by filtering).
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb" successfully created.
```

Why is the /dev/sda4 device not being found?
I have no filters in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`

OS: Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 2):

The only thing an extended partition can do is contain one or more logical partitions (/dev/sdXn where n>=5). If you have no need for more partitions on the disk then you should create a fourth primary partition instead.